# Bypass trigger on external updates

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api

I have a trigger that I only want to process if the update was done internally to Salesforce but I want to bypass the trigger logic if it comes from an external API like the Composite API. If the insert/update was caused by a future or batch I know I can use `System.isBatch()` or `System.isFuture()` to bypass the processing but I can't seem to figure out how to bypass from external APIs.

My use case is a system that syncs both ways with Salesforce. If the record is created/updated in Salesforce it should fire my trigger to run the custom code to update the external system. The external system will update Salesforce via Composite API. Right now when the external system tries to update Salesforce via the Composite API my trigger is fired which tries to send it back to the external system when there isn't a need. I want to avoid that.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This, to me, sounds like a job for the [Quiddity Enum](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_System_Quiddity.htm) (which is accessible through the [Request class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Request.htm#topic-title)).

As far as I know, using the `Composite` resource means that the Request Quiddity should be `REST`. Simply add a check against the current request's quiddity to your trigger.

e.g.

```java
...trigger...{
    if(Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity() == System.Quiddity.REST){
        // current request initiated from a REST call, skip work by
        //   returning early
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunate that didn't work. Both UI and Composite API returned `SYNCHRONOUS` for the Quiddity value. I think if it was a custom Apex API using RestResource it might come back with `REST`. Anyways, I think I found another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this issue. Using `System.URL.getCurrentRequestUrl()` I am able to get the URL that triggered the update.

From the Salesforce UI I got `/aura?r=157&aura.RecordUi.updateRecord=1`

When calling the Composite API I got `/services/data/v55.0/composite/graph`

So my solution is to just bypass the trigger logic if the URL contains `services/data` which is part of external API endpoints but not from Salesforce pages.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution! I'm going to use something similar in order to determine the source of the action made in Salesforce.